# Using rescale based on categories in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains tiers and scores.  I want to rescale the scores based on the tier with tier 5 from 100-91, tier 4 from 90-81, tier 3 from 80-71 etc.  A sample of the data is as follows...

```
Tier Score  
1 95  
2 85  
3 90  
3 87  
1 90  
4 88  
5 90  
2 90  
5 75  
3 80  
4 72  
1 86  
5 70
```

What I have so far is

```
library(scales)
df$scale = ifelse(df$tier == "5", rescale(df[df$tier == "5",]$score, to = c(91, 100)), df$scale)
```

and the output is NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a list containing the limits for `rescale`. The first list element is for `Tier` 1, the second list element is for `Tier` 2 etc.

```
limits <- list(c(60, 51), c(61, 70), c(71, 80), c(81, 90), c(91, 100))
```

You can use this list in the following `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Tier) %>%
   mutate(scale = rescale(Score, to = limits[[first(Tier)]]))
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 13 x 3
# Groups:   Tier [5]
    Tier Score scale
   <int> <int> <dbl>
 1     1    95  51  
 2     2    85  61  
 3     3    90  80  
 4     3    87  77.3
 5     1    90  56  
 6     4    88  90  
 7     5    90 100  
 8     2    90  70  
 9     5    75  93.2
10     3    80  71  
11     4    72  81  
12     1    86  60  
13     5    70  91
```

Comment: awesome this seems like it will do what i want, what about if i wanted scales that are not totally independent? suppose tier 5 is 98-92, tier 4 is 93-87, tier 3 is 88-82 tier 2 is 83-78 and tier 1 is 79-75. thanks

Comment: it gives me the error "x must be length 1 or 2" what is the `first` referring to in limits[[first(Tier)]]? @sven

Comment: @user10256905 It refers to the first value of `Tier`.

Comment: could NA values in Tier be giving me that error? and if so is there a way to not include rows where Tier is na?

Comment: @user10256905 The command will return `NA` for rows where `Tier` is` NA`. Please provide a *reproducible* example.